# Laravel - @method static in comments in empty model - what am I looking at here

Tags: php, laravel, methods, model

So I'm still going through the process of learning more in depth PHP / Laravel, having completed one project and taking on another. The codebase supplied has several seemingly empty models with blocks of code in the comments. My concerns are more about the `@method` entries over the `@property` ones.

My question is simply, what am I looking at here? Should I be concerned about modifying it. Is there a resource that covers this that my google-fu has missed?

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

/**
 * App\FitOption
 *
 * @property int $id
 * @property string $option_type
 * @property string $option_name
 * @property float $option_price
 * @property \Illuminate\Support\Carbon|null $created_at
 * @property \Illuminate\Support\Carbon|null $updated_at
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\FitOption newModelQuery()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\FitOption newQuery()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\FitOption query()
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\FitOption whereCreatedAt($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\FitOption whereId($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\FitOption whereOptionName($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\FitOption whereOptionPrice($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\FitOption whereOptionType($value)
 * @method static \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder|\App\FitOption whereUpdatedAt($value)
 * @mixin \Eloquent
 */
class FitOption extends Model
{
    //
}
```

Comment: can you find these function implementations in the project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was looking at [PhpDoc comments](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/phpdoc-comments.html?gclid=Cj0KCQjwwLKFBhDPARIsAPzPi-LLcfn39TigqYnm6jPnxNiGsvWYgCQ2JycV3_w4Dx6jozlL3eh15ZMaAgAUEALw_wcB) and I need not have worried about them.